# Applocker popup message

Tags: applocker

We are using Applocker to restrict access to some programs, but we would like to do so silently.
Is there a way to applock an app but *disable* the "administrator has blocked access to this program" pop up message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most you can do with applocker is to set a custom URL that they can click on to get More Information from you/IT as to why the app was blocked and perhaps a number or email address to call to get permissions to that app.

See here for more information: [Display a Custom URL Message When Users Try to Run a Blocked Application](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee791778%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Without an error message, most users would simply be calling the Helpdesk saying "I double clicked and nothing happened"...so I'm guessing that's why MS doesn't allow for the disable of the error message entirely.